# How can I delete N number of rows and columns of a 2d array selected by the user in c

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am writing a piece of code that uses a struct containing a 2d array and predetermined functions which I have listed with comments describing what the function does.

```
struct matrix
{
    char name;
    int mValues[10][10[;
    int nrows;
    int ncols;
};
/** Function Prototypes**/

// Lets user name, choose dimensions and populates matrix from a 10x10 .txt file
void matrixInput(struct matrix *matA); 

// Asks the user to choose how many rows to delete and select which rows 
// Asks the user to choose how many columns to delete and select which columns.
// The result should be a sub matrix of the input matrix stored in a new struct matrix
void subMatrix(struct matrix m1, struct matrix *m2);

// What the Input/Output should look like

How many rows do you want to delete? : 2

Please enter, one per row, the number(s) of the 2 rows you want to delete : 2
Please enter, one per row, the number(s) of the 2 rows you want to delete : 1

How many columns do you want to delete? : 3

Please enter, one per column, the number(s) of the 3 columns you want to delete : 4
Please enter, one per column, the number(s) of the 3 columns you want to delete : 2
Please enter, one per column, the number(s) of the 3 columns you want to delete : 5

// Displays sub matrix
```

It's the last function I am having problems with.

I know the size of the input matrix and I think that I need to some how tell the complier pass the values of the input matrix to the new struct matrix while excluding the value of the user input for row/col number to be deleted. I'm not sure if this could be done in a nested loop or if I would need other variables to store values.

I know how to read and pass values at a given index but I'm stuck for ideas when it comes to not reading and passing values at a given index.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

*Side note, any tips on how to improve the quality of my question is welcomed.*

Comment: Are all matrices 10x10? Creating a smaller matrix using that definition seems kind of impossible.

Comment: @cadaniluk The input matrix can be up to 10x10, the dimensions are defined by user input, the .txt file has a list of 10x10 integers. 
So if user inputs 7x4 I would be deleting rows and columns from a 7x4 matrix and displaying the resulting sub matrix.

Comment: Then why not simple do as the function description says and create a new `struct matrix` with new `nrows` and `ncols` values and store the remaining values accordingly? Try to code it and if you get stuck then, ask about it. Nested loops will probably work, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which columns and rows to delete, and you are sure that the result is going to fit in the new matrix, then just do a  nested loop and tell it to ignore a certain range of values.

But what you really want to do is create the new matrix inside the copying function and return it. If they are created dynamically you can ignore assignment of the columns or rows you are trying to copy in the same way (nested loops) and fit it exactly with the size you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily store delete information in a matrix, because `matrix->values[0][0]` could refer to either row or column. It's easier to declare to integers instead.

The function `void subMatrix(struct matrix m1,...)` is technically okay if you don't want to change `m1`, but this makes an extra copy of `m1` which is not efficient. It's better to use `void subMatrix(const struct matrix *source,...)` instead.

You can also use dynamic allocation instead of fixed array of `value[10][10]`. Example:

```
struct matrix {
    int **data;
    int rows;
    int cols;
};

void create(struct matrix *m, int rows, int cols)
{
    m->rows = rows;
    m->cols = cols;
    m->data = malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        m->data[r] = malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
}

void destroy(struct matrix *m)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++)
        free(m->data[i]);
    free(m->data);
}

void print(const struct matrix *m)
{
    for(int r = 0; r < m->rows; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < m->cols; c++)
            printf("%4d", m->data[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void change(struct matrix *new, struct matrix *m, int *delete_rows, int *delete_cols)
{
    int rows = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < m->rows; row++)
        if(!delete_rows[row])
            rows++;
    int cols = 0;
    for(int col = 0; col< m->cols; col++)
        if(!delete_cols[col])
            cols++;
    create(new, rows, cols);

    int next_row = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < m->rows; row++)
    {
        if(delete_rows[row]) continue;
        int next_col = 0;
        for(int col = 0; col < m->cols; col++)
        {
            if(delete_cols[col]) continue;
            new->data[next_row][next_col] = m->data[row][col];
            next_col++;
        }
        next_row++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct matrix m;
    create(&m, 10, 10);
    for(int r = 0; r < m.rows; r++)
        for(int c = 0; c < m.rows; c++)
            m.data[r][c] = r * 100 + c;
    print(&m);

    //get delete information
    int delete_rows[10] = { 0 };
    int delete_cols[10] = { 0 };
    delete_rows[0] = 1;//delete row 0
    delete_cols[7] = 1;//delete col 7

    struct matrix new;
    change(&new, &m, delete_rows, delete_cols);
    print(&new);
    destroy(&m);
    destroy(&new);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have to use the function as it is declared, however, your answer is more than helpful. I have an exam on Tuesday, after I will return to my problem and I will post my solution and or ask for further clarification. Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question.